# Geodatabase topology and geometric network on the same data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, topology, geometric-network, schematics

I know that I can't have a topology and geometric network on the same data in the same dataset in ArcSDE. But is there any solution how to do this? I need geometric network for generating diagrams via schematics extension. And on the same data I want build topology to avoid topology errors.
Is it possible to make two replicas of the GDB on the first replica work with geometric network and schematics and on the second replica build topology and after that synchronize the both replicas together?

Comment: Geometric networks do enforce topological rules. Is there a reason configuring geometric network rules won't work for you? If this is for an initial network build, perhaps you could create topology rules, fix the errors, drop the topology, and then build your network.

Comment: No data is ever ***in*** ArcSDE, only accessed ***through*** ArcSDE. Please specify the database product in use and the geometry storage option used in that RDBMS.

Comment: It's SQL Server Enterprise Geodatabase

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to propagate changes to a network once built, as the build process is where the conversion from geometry to network format takes place.  In other words, any changes to your network caused by topology fixing would need to be rebuilt into a new network before generating the diagrams.  So the network operations will always need to be downstream of the topology.

Presumably it is possible to script the diagram creation process if it needs to be run multiple times after topology edits, and this would solve the problem of 'syncing' the datasets.